# Assigning variables inside a command inside a Makefile target

Tags: shell, unix, makefile, autotools, automake

So I have this fragment of code in a `Makefile.am` file (automake):

```
RUNNER = \
    for asm in $${TEST_ASSEMBLIES}; do \
            echo -e "Running tests on $${asm}..."; \
            $(ENV_OPTIONS) $(NUNIT_CONSOLE) -nologo -noshadow $$asm; \
            echo $$?; \
    done

test:
    @pushd $(DIR_BIN) &>/dev/null; \
    export TEST_ASSEMBLIES="$(TEST_ASSEMBLIES)"; $(RUNNER); \
    popd &>/dev/null;
```

The statement `echo $$?;` works: it prints 0 when the test works and 1 when it fails.

But what I'm trying to do is have a global var called `GLOBAL_EXIT_CODE` or something, which would have 0 if all tests run well, or 1 if **any** of the tests fail. But for the life of me, I cannot even capture the value of `$$?` in a variable. I've tried numerous things: export, assignemnt via simple "VAR = $$?", also with the `+=` operator... etc. Nothing works! :(

The reason I want to have a variable `GLOBAL_EXIT_CODE` is so I can do `exit $GLOBAL_EXIT_CODE` in the `test` target, in case its value was higher than zero, in order to have the command `make test` return an error.

Comment: Why not use automake's built-in test suite support?

Comment: can you elaborate? give a URL where that is documented?

Comment: The manual is here: http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Tests.html It could be a matter of simply specifying a `TESTS` variable (instead of `TEST_ASSEMBLIES`), and a custom `LOG_DRIVER` or `LOG_DRIVER` (possibly what your `RUNNER` does).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that.  You have to remember that the recipe is *running in a shell* that make has invoked.  That's a separate process, not in the make process.

There's no way that anything that happens in the shell (a child process) can change any aspect of make (the parent process) such as set a make variable.  Once the shell exits, all the information it had is lost.  The only thing that make gets back from the shell is the ultimate exit code; that's how make decides whether the command succeeded or failed.

The only way to do this is to write the value to a file and then have make read the file and put the resulting value into a make variable.

ETA:

But if all you want to do is preserve the exit code within the shell (as your edits say), then you don't need a `make` variable at all.  You need a shell variable, and that's very easy.  Also, note that `make` always invokes `/bin/sh` which is a POSIX shell, and `pushd` and `popd` are bash shell features, so this makefile is not portable.  Luckily, there's no point in doing the `pushd` or `popd` anyway, because the working directory (in a POSIX system) is a feature of an individual process (the shell in this case) so any directory changes you make inside the shell only impact that shell and are gone when the shell exits.

So, try something like this:

```
RUNNER = \
    RETURN=0; \
    for asm in $${TEST_ASSEMBLIES}; do \
        echo -e "Running tests on $${asm}..."; \
        $(ENV_OPTIONS) $(NUNIT_CONSOLE) -nologo -noshadow $$asm \
            || RETURN=$$?; \
    done

test:
        @export TEST_ASSEMBLIES="$(TEST_ASSEMBLIES)"; \
         $(RUNNER); \
         exit $$RETURN
```

I don't really understand why you're setting the shell variable `TEST_ASSEMBLIES` to the value of the make variable `$(TEST_ASSEMBLIES)`.  It's not necessary, but it will work.

Comment: edited question to add info about GLOBAL_EXIT_CODE motivation

Answer (score 1):

I'm expanding my comment into an answer; this is the automake way to solve the problem, since the other answer focuses on plain make.

Assuming your `TEST_ASSEMBLIES` is a list of programs that can be run in stand-alone fashion:

```
TESTS = $(TEST_ASSEMBLIES)
```

Done. Do a `make check` and you should see the summary of the tests. By default automake will use its own test driver, which runs each test, redirects the output to a log file, and prints out the summary.

If you need the tests to be run by a special program, use the `LOG_COMPILER` variable:

```
TESTS = $(TEST_ASSEMBLIES)
LOG_COMPILER = $(NUNIT_CONSOLE)
AM_LOG_FLAGS = -nologo -noshadow
```

If you need environment variables set up (is that what `ENV_OPTIONS` does?), you can use `AM_TESTS_ENVIRONMENT` for that.